# Custom JSON format from dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a following test code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
  
x = np.array([['101', 'title1', 'body1', 'answer1'], ['102', 'title2', 'body2', 'answer2'], ['103', 'title3', 'body3', 'answer3']])
   
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'])
df.head()
```

```
 | col1 |col2   |col3   |col4
---------------------------------
0|  101 |title1 |body1  |answer1
1|  102 |title2 |body2  |answer2
2|  103 |title3 |body3  |answer3
```

I want a json output of this format

```
{"index": {"_id": "col1"}}
{"title": "col2", "body": "col3", "answer": "col4"}
```

Like

```
{"index": {"_id": "101"}}
{"title": "title1", "body": "body1", "answer": "answer1"}
```

For every rows in the dataframe.

Could anyone shine some light?

Answer (score 1):

It's not dificult, I recommend you read at documentations of library.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = np.array([['101', 'title1', 'body1', 'answer1'], ['102', 'title2', 'body2', 'answer2'],
              ['103', 'title3', 'body3', 'answer3']])

df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'])
djson=df.to_json()
print(djson)
```

Answer (score 0):

Raphael's answer is probably the best approach to your problem (In case you want it row-wise, you can go ahead and do `df.transpose` before the `df.to_json()`); however, if what you really want is to define the json string exactly as you have there (That would be different from column names), you can do something like this:

```
jsons = []
json_string = '{{"index": {{"_id": "{index}"}}}}{{"title": "{title}", "body": "{body}", "answer": "{answer}"}}'

for row in range(len(df)):
    data = [df.iloc[row, x] for x in range(len(df.columns))]
    jsons.append(json_string.format(index=data[0],title=data[1],body=data[2], answer=data[3]))
```

And then get the list of json strings in the `jsons` variable. In case you need to convert into object, you can use the json library, and use `json.loads()`

Answer (score 0):

Create a json string of how you want your output to look and format it on the dataframe.

For curl operations (while using ElasticSearch and Kibana), make sure to split the json string below

```
json_string = '{{"index": {{"_id": "{index}"}}}}{{"title": "{title}", "body": "{body}", "answer": "{answer}"}}'
```

will give output in json as

```
{"index": {"_id": "101"}}{"title": "title1", "body": "body1", "answer": "answer1"}
```

For output to be like this

```
{"index": {"_id": "101"}}
{"title": "title1", "body": "body1", "answer": "answer1"}
```

use

```
json_string1 = '{{"index": {{"_id": "{index}"}}}}'
json_string2 = '{{"title": "{title}", "body": "{body}", "answer": "{answer}"}}'
```

Here is the complete code (Convert json list to json object by json.dumps() followed by json.loads()

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import json
  
x = np.array([['101', 'title1', 'body1', 'answer1'], ['102', 'title2', 'body2', 'answer2'], ['103', 'title3', 'body3', 'answer3']])
   
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'])

jsons = []
json_string1 = '{{"index": {{"_id": "{index}"}}}}'
json_string2 = '{{"title": "{title}", "body": "{body}", "answer": "{answer}"}}'

for row in range(len(df)):
    data = [df.iloc[row, x] for x in range(len(df.columns))]
    jsons.append(json_string1.format(index=data[0]))
    jsons.append(json_string2.format(title=data[1],body=data[2], answer=data[3]))

with open("filename.json", "w") as fp:
    for i in range(len(jsons)):
        x = json.dumps(jsons[i])
        y = json.loads(x)
        fp.write("%s\n" % y)
```